# Let $X_i\sim U(a,b)$. Suppose that $a$ is known, find the UMVUE of parameter $b$.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,...,X_n$,  be  iid  random  variables  from  the  continuous  uniform  distribution  on  the  interval $(a,b)$.  Suppose that $a$ is known, find the UMVUE of parameter $b$.

I'm stuck with this question. I have been trying to find a complete and sufficient statistic for $b$, but I´m only able to find it for $U(0,b)$. Maybe this way is more complicated to find the UMVUE($b$) but I'm now interested in finding the complete and sufficient statistic for $b$.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: It seems like if you have the UMVUE for the case $a=0$, you can reduce to this case by replacing the random variables $X_i$ with $X_i - a$, then adding $a$ to that answer.

Comment: This is entirely like the $U(0,b)$ exercise. Where are you stuck?